# AWS Glue job, Python script for datetime.today().strftime(%y/%m/%d) getting UTC date & time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-glue

AWS Glue job, Python script for datetime.today().strftime(%y/%m/%d) getting UTC date & time NOT USA date & time. Basically tomorrow date & time, if you run above function.
How to get US date & time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current time in `UTC` with your given format `%y/%m/%d`, you can use the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime

time_now_utc = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%y/%m/%d")
```

If you want the current time at a different timezone, you can use `pytz` lib, and do the following:

```py
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
time_now_ny = datetime.now(tz).strftime("%y/%m/%d")
```

Since USA has multiple timezones, select the specific region you want.
To list all the regions in `pytz`, run the following:

```py
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.all_timezones
['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa', ...]
```

Comment: Central time zone so it would be tz = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago') then?